# 404 error when adding new MVC page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

Dumb question, I am modifying in Visual studio 2012 an existing MVC site.  The site works fine in development (ie i can get to the login page, route to existing pages, etc).  But when I try to add a page /Views/UserEdit/UserEdit.cshtml - I can't get to that page.  I get a 404 error when trying to call it when I run IIS express from visual studio (ie this url:  http://localhost:53997/UserEdit/UserEdit)

So do I need to do anything to copy the page to the development website?  Seems like this is the issue.   I checked the existing pages and they do not have any different settings for the cshtml page.  Is there some list of files that are deployed that I need to modify?

Comment: Do you have an action method called `UserEdit` in `UserEditController` ?

Comment: It's not clear whether or not you have a controller action behind the page.  Can you show us the code that you have?  Your controller action would render this new  view

Comment: Okay I don't have a control.  So I guess that would help!  Thanks.

Comment: Edit:  I added the controller and now can see the page.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not directly add a view file and try to access that. You should add an action method though which you will return the view to the browser.

When a request comes for, `yourSiteName.com/UserEdit/UserEdit` , with the default route configuration, MVC will try to look for a controller called `UserEdit` and an action method called `UserEdit` . So you need to make sure you have those.

```
public class UserEditController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult UserEdit()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

Make sure you have `UserEdit.cshtml` in `~/Views/UserEdit/` location.